# Create a card Timeline in Glass App

Tags: android, android-viewpager, google-glass, google-gdk

Can we create our own cards timeline. I want to display multiple cards in the same way as in the glass timeline.

One option is to use the CardScrollAdapter for making a custom timeline. Is there any other way.?

What if i want different option on different cards? How will i implement this functionality on cardScrollAdapter?

Also what if i don't want to use cards (as they don't have much customization option) and want to use other Android layouts for this purpose. How should i implement the timeline then. Should i use fragments with viewflipper or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

override getView and getItem in the CardScrollAdapter to provide a variety of views, as varied as you wish. You could use a switch statement or go further with a state pattern to provide the correct view for the given card/page/screen.